# gRPC: Asynchronous client thread safety clarification

Tags: c++, grpc

In gRPC, we can use an async client to send multiple calls at the same time.
For example, with a service that has a RPC method `Foo()`, we need to call, in this order:

1. First `auto reader = stub.AsyncFoo(&client_context, request, &completion_queue)`
2. Then `reader->Finish(&response, &status, call_data)`
3. Finally `completion_queue.Next()` to get the status of the RPC.

My questions about thread safety are the following:

1. Is it thread safe to call `Next()` and `AsyncFoo()` at the same time in different threads?
2. Is it thread safe to call `Next()` and `Finish()` at the same time in different threads?
3. Is it thread safe to call multiple `AsyncFoo()` for different call data at the same time in different thread?
4. Is it thread safe to call multiple `Finish()` for different call data at the same time in different thread?
5. For all the cases, if it is thread-safe: Is it thread-safe *only* when different threads are working with different stub or does it work also for the same stub?